# Inserting into Oracle database

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc

I tried everything possible but it's not working. I'm trying to insert records into a database on the server using Datasource it worked for SELECT statement but doesn't work for INSERT statement. Is there anything I need to do apart from this code?

Prepared Statement

```
insertCampusian = connection.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO CAMPUSIAN ( CAMPUSIAN_USER_NAME, CAMPUSIAN_FIRST_NAME, "
                    + "CAMPUSIAN_LAST_NAME, CAMPUSIAN_PASSWORD, CAMPUSIAN_PHONE_NO, CAMPUSIAN_EMAIL, CAMPUSIAN_MARITAL_STATUS, "
                    + "CAMPUSIAN_SEX ) VALUES( ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ? )");
```

For inserting

```
public boolean register(Campusian campusian) {
        try {
            insertCampusian.setString(1, campusian.getUserName());
            insertCampusian.setString(2, campusian.getFirstName());
            insertCampusian.setString(3, campusian.getLastName());
            insertCampusian.setString(4, campusian.getPassword());
            insertCampusian.setString(5, campusian.getPhoneNo());
            insertCampusian.setString(6, campusian.getEmail());
            insertCampusian.setString(7, campusian.getMaritalStatus());
            insertCampusian.setString(8, campusian.getSex());

            boolean result = insertCampusian.execute();
            System.out.println("Is Successful: "+result);
            if (!result) {
                //connection.rollback();
                return false;
            }
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            System.out.println("ERROR.. "+ex);
            Logger.getLogger(CampusianDataBaseBean.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        //connection.commit();
        return true;
    }
```

Comment: try insertCampusian.executeQuery() or insertCampusian.executeUpdate()

Comment: What error are you getting? How do you know it is not working? Do you have access to update the table?

Comment: I tried also using executeUpdate() method it return 0 but when i checked the table noting was found

Comment: The return value of `execute()` doesn't mean what you think it means. It is not about the success or failure of the statement, but what the first 'return value' of the statement is (an update count or a result set).

Comment: I checked the database table value inserted using insert statement was not found

Comment: Do you ever commit the insert?

Answer (score 1):

try to change this line

```
boolean result = insertCampusian.execute();
```

By this line:

```
int result = insertCampusian.executeUpdate();
```

Read more about [`PreparedStatement.executeUpdate()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html)

Java Doc:

> Executes the SQL statement in this PreparedStatement object, which must be an SQL Data Manipulation Language (DML) statement, such as INSERT, UPDATE or DELETE; or an SQL statement that returns nothing, such as a DDL statement.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `executeUpdate()` method to write records into a database, and the `executeQuery()` for a select

Comment: I tried also using executeUpdate() method it return 0 but when i checked the table noting was found

Comment: Database was loaded well, i can pull out data from the table but i cant insert

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Guys I finally found what the problem was. By default DML is auto-commit, since I disabled auto-commit I have to do that any time I'm using DML. So what i did was to commit after every Insertion. This solves the problem